# How can I insert an object graph by using MikroORM?

Tags: javascript, orm, mikro-orm

I'm trying to create and update multiple entities (models) at once. I did this in objection ORM by using `insertGraph` API which actually inserts entity if it has no id and updates if it has id.

Is there a similar API in MikroORM?

Currently I'm doing this:

```js
app.put('/articles', async (req, res) => {
  const save = req.body.articles.map(async (dto) => {
    const article = Object.assign(new Article(), dto)
    await req.em.persistAndFlush(article)
  })


  await Promise.all(save)
  res.send({ ok: true })
})
```

but it generates multiple transactions and I want to everything in single transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that when using `persistAndFlush` method, you immediately persist the entity to database by awaiting the promise. Instead you can call `em.persistLater(article)` to mark it for persisting. Then call `em.flush()` afterwards, which will commit all changes to database inside single transaction.

```
app.put('/articles', async (req, res) => {
  req.body.articles.forEach(dto => {
    const article = Object.assign(new Article(), dto)
    req.em.persistLater(article)
  })

  await req.em.flush() // save everything to database inside single transaction
  res.send({ ok: true })
})
```

You can make it even simpler by preparing all entities into one array, and `persistAndFlush` that instead:

```
app.put('/articles', async (req, res) => {
  const articles = req.body.articles.map(dto => Object.assign(new Article(), dto))
  await req.em.persistAndFlush(articles) // save everything to database inside single transaction
  res.send({ ok: true })
})
```

Also, instead of using `Object.assign()`, you can use `IEntity.assign()` method on the entity, which will also take care of creating references from plain identifiers:

```
const article = new Article().assign(dto)
```

More about `IEntity.assign()` can be found in the docs:

https://b4nan.github.io/mikro-orm/entity-helper/

You could also use `EntityManager.create()` helper, which will construct the entity for you - the benefit of this is that it will automatically handle [constructor parameters](https://b4nan.github.io/mikro-orm/entity-constructors/), passing them to constructor instead of assigning them directly.

```
const article = req.em.create(Article, dto)
```